# Type synonym in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to create a "type synonym" in oracle? Something like:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM EmailType FOR VARCHAR2(120);
```

Comment: You have Types for that.

Comment: But what´s the syntax? I´ve tried this CREATE TYPE EmailType AS VARCHAR2(120);, but I got a ORA-24344 success with compilation error.

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EmailType AS OBJECT(  EMail VARCHAR2(120));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that, but you might want to use SUBTYPE.
Place SUBTYPE declaration inside of package and use that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SUBTYPES_PKG IS
  SUBTYPE EMAIL IS VARCHAR2(120);
END;
```

Comment: So could then use subtype: l_email_variable SUBTYPES_PKG.EMAIL;

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is known in other databases as a "domain" - and there ain't no domains in Oracle.  Sorry for the bad news.  To use a TYPE in Oracle you'll need something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMAILTYPE AS OBJECT
  (
  strEmail  VARCHAR2(120)
  )
```

and then you'll probably need to define constructors and methods to operate on your type.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Tegiri: I respectfully disagree.  Oracle's type system, in my experience, is a heavyweight solution to the problem of creating meaningful names for 'kinds' of data which brings with it an entire pile of undesireable baggage.  I've used both and *for my uses* I find domains a better solution.  Others will doubtless disagree.  I'd be happy if I could use PL/SQL-ish syntax like "ALTER TABLE X ADD (Y  DOMAIN_NAME.TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE)" when adding a new column but this is not allowed.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a database at the moment, so I'll check in the morning but I'm fairly sure you can do this. Although you can't create an object as a public synonym, you can create a synonym on **almost** any object.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EmailType AS OBJECT( EMail VARCHAR2(120));
create or replace public synonym emailtype  for emailtype;
```

Comment: I think this is ok, but I would like to use the "EmailType" as a synonym for VARCHAR2(120)

Comment: This will create `emailtype` as a synonym for `varchar2(120)`, people will still be able to type varchar2(120) though. You shouldn't really stop them. What happens if someone needs create another type with varchar2(120) in and can't?